# Git merge lists same branch multiple times

Tags: git, merge, git-extensions

I am using `git extensions` to merge by branches. However, I see same branch listed multiple times with different paths. I know that they refer to the same thing but why are they listed multiple times ? Is there any difference between them that I am not aware of ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These branches are not actually the same thing. `origin/{branchname}` is a [remote tracking branch](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches). Remote tracking branches represent a snapshot of the code as it existed on the `origin` repository the last time you did a `git fetch` or a `git push` for that branch.